# selecting all rows 7 days from now based on unix timestamp and current date

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have a table with the following fields:

```
id - int
name - int
the_date - int
```

`the_date` is a unix timestamp for when the row was added

Now I am trying to write a query that will select all rows on the day that is 7 days from now. I'm not talking about select the rows >= 7 days from `time()`, I need to grab the current day using `time()`, and then run a SELECT that grabs all the rows that were inserted on the day that is 7 days from the `time()`.

I know how to do it so its within 7 days from the `time()` with a simple >= SELECT, but I don't know how to do it so it selects all rows whose unix timestamp is on that particular day (7 days from now).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're gonna select the records that will be inserted 7 days from now? Wow I want a query like that as well and predict the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The points of intrest here,

- i use curdate() to get the current DATE, not DATETIME.
- i add 7 days and convert to unix time, which yields the starting second of that day
- i do the same for the next day
- i structure the where clause to be >= or equal to the target day, but < the start of the next day. This gives a range of seconds that fully covers the target day.
- i dont use any functions on the column itself. This is important because if i did, mysql wouldn't be abl;e to use any indexes that exist on the column to fullfill the query.

---

```
where the_date >= unix_timestamp(curdate() + interval 7 day)
  and the_date < unix_timestamp(curdate() + interval 8 day)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$todayParts = getdate();    
$startToday = mktime(0, 0, 0, $todayParts['mon'], $todayParts['mday'], $todayParts['year']);
$sevebDaysFromNow = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
$seventhStart = $startToday + $sevebDaysFromNow;
$seventhEnd = $seventhStart + 60 * 60 * 24;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE the_date BETWEEN $seventhStart AND $seventEnd";
```

This will calculate 7 days from the start of the day you are now. Hope this helps

Comment: i know how to do this...i need all the rows that were added on that date, as in from 12am to 12pm on that day.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM `dbname1`.`test`
  WHERE 
    date(FROM_UNIXTIME(`the_date`)) = ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Comment: will this select all rows from 12am - 12pm 7 days from now?

Comment: `date()` will take the date portion of a date/time stamp i.e 2012-05-10.   which will cover a whole day  00:00 to 23:59